# My HP-Z440 Tower workstation does not power on

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a weird issue. My HPZ440 workstation does not power on. When i hand it over for troubleshooting, the guy tells me that it doesn't have any problem and is working fine. Then it works for a day or two. Afterwards when I try to power it ON again, it won't power ON. This cycle had happened three times, and now it won't power ON again.

The computer doesn't power on but when I insert external USB hard drive in the front USB port, i can see the LED blinking.

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?

The solution that I found online and tried.

- Plug out all the peripheral devices, hold power button for about 15 secs to drain all the capacitors and then start again.

Comment: Power on a USB port when the computer is turned off can be normal. Plenty of USB ports these days allow you to say charge a phone without having to turn on the computer. As for your problem, it could be a problem in the power button itself. You can disconnect it from the motherboard and short the 2 power pins to start the PC. It could also be your power supply has seen its best days. Have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting that ? Also, if its a workstation at your job, just have the tech guy figure it out!

Comment: This is my personal workstation. Three times, i hand it over to repairing guy. He just plug it in in front of me and the computer starts and works fine. But when i bring it back home, it works for the day and when i shut down and try to turn it ON again, it won't. So if the power supply or power button is faulty, i think it shouldn't  work with repairing guy as well.